# how to design grouped input text fields in one rounded corner box in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

can anyone tell me how can I put multiple text input fields in one grouped rounded corner box?

also with text place holder.

please see the attached image

[image: input rounded corner box]

I was trying from my side the code bellow:

```
<div data-role="content" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <form id="frmLogin" action="#" method="POST" data-transition="slide">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical">

        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <label id="txtLoginName" for="loginName"></label>
          <input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName" value=""  class="required"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <label id="txtLoginPassword" for="loginPassword"></label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="loginPassword" value="" class="required"/>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a id="btnLoginSubmit" href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true"></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you try from your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have your CSS to work with. So, here is a simple alternative.

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 2px #ddd solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
}
div input {
    border: none;
    width: 260px;
    padding: 20px;
}
div input:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text"  value="email"/>
    <input type="password" value="password" />
</div>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaYG/)

Comment: well, I did not add the css yet because I was wondering if I can achieve this with jQuery mobile css, since I can group check boxes and radio buttons, but not input text....

Comment: The question clearly says in jQuery Mobile. This does not work with jQuery Mobile.